# How can I reinstall or recompile already installed packages in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to reinstall or recompile an already installed package in Julia? I did not find any hints in the official documentation. `whos()` did not reveal anything useful either.

Best

---

As was pointed out in the answer below by @ivarne my question can also be understood as:

"How can I reload a package that has been loaded with `import` or `using` in a Julia session?"

This question has also been answered by @ivarne.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can re-run the package build script with `Pkg.build("pkgname")`. The actual compiling of the packages is just in time so they are complied when you load them.

Comment: i have to restart my REPL each time i want to do this, but otherwise works (y)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the terminology you use, but if you think about reloading a package (with import or using), it is complicated and the best approach is to restart Julia.

A function called `reload()` exists, but it has some limitations. While developing a Package, you might consider using something like the [Autoreload.jl](https://github.com/malmaud/Autoreload.jl) package to make it easier to reload the files you are working on.

Comment: Great! I just answered the different interpretation of the question instead of asking for clarification.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the other possible interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing package and heve it installed using `dev` command, than `Base.compilecache(Base.PkgId(PDFIO))` does the job.
In this case `PDFIO` is the package that I'm working on. 
It is more convenient than restarting julia.